# Difference between fetching with server cursor vs streaming

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

What's the difference, behaviour-wise, between fetching results using *server cursors* and fetching using *streaming*?

The former (*server cursors*) can be activated:

- For every statement by setting [`useCursorFetch=true`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) and [`defaultFetchSize=N`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) in the connection properties. (Where *N* is a number greater than zero.)
- Or individual statements by initially setting `useCursorFetch=true` or `com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setUseCursorFetch(true)` on the connection, followed by `java.sql.Statement.setFetchSize(N)` on the statement.

The latter ([*streaming*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html)) can be activated:

- On individual statements by setting `java.sql.Statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` or by calling `com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.enableStreamingResults()` on the statment.
- And probably on every statement by setting `defaultFetchSize=X` in the connection properties, where *X* is a number equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

**What does one need to consider when developing with these alternative methods?**  A good answer may touch on topics such as *performance*, *lock holding*, and *resource allocation (/ deallocation)*.

Answer (score 3):

Examining Mysql's Connector/J source code (v5.1.39):

When using server cursor (`setUseCursorFetch(true)`) and if the result set type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, it seems like the "streaming" mode is just a special case where the fetched block is 1-row only:

```
////// RowDataCursor.java /////////

private void fetchMoreRows() throws SQLException {
    ...

    synchronized (this.owner.connection.getConnectionMutex()) {
        ...

        int numRowsToFetch = this.owner.getFetchSize();
        ...

        if (numRowsToFetch == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            // Handle the case where the user used 'old' streaming result sets

            numRowsToFetch = 1;
        }
```

See also `MysqlIO.java` for the conditions where `RowDataCursor` is instantiated:

```
    //
    // Handle cursor-based fetch first
    //

    if (this.connection.versionMeetsMinimum(5, 0, 2) && this.connection.getUseCursorFetch() && isBinaryEncoded && callingStatement != null
            && callingStatement.getFetchSize() != 0 && callingStatement.getResultSetType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) {
        ServerPreparedStatement prepStmt = (com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement) callingStatement;

        boolean usingCursor = true;
```

MySQL 5.7 documentation indicates that using server cursor generates a temporary table at the server side (memory table if size allows) so this may affect server performance.